Injectivity of Kernel Operator in Lp spaces
here is the context: Let $T$ be a kernel operator from $L^1(\mu)$ to $L^1(\nu)$ (probability measures in my problem), defined by
$ (Tf)(x) = \int f(y) \, k(x,y) \, \mu(dy). $
More generally, is there a criterion for injectivity for this kind of kernel operator mapping different $L^p$ spaces?

k(x,y)>=0 a.e in my problem

See https://mathoverflow.net/questions/355872/injectivity-of-an-integral-operator

no my operator is not compact in general and not in an hilbert space and T* T is no defined
